# AutoMapper with LINQ condition

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using AutoMapper in a C# project.
My `MyEntity` BO is mapped to several DTOs this way:

```cs
public class MyEntityDto
{
    public MyEntitySubDto1 MyEntitySubDto1 {get; set;}
    public MyEntitySubDto2 MyEntitySubDto2 {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

AutoMapper perfectly manages to handle this:

```cs
CreateMap<MyEntity, MyEntityDto>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.MyEntitySubDto1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.MyEntitySubDto1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src))
         
        .ReverseMap();
```

Now comes the difficulty. :)
`MyEntity` has a 1-N association with `MySubEntity`.
I want to map to `MyEntitySubDto1` properties of a very specific element of the `MySubEntity` collection (I know the LINQ query to get the very one that I want).

I changed my mapping for something like this:

```cs
CreateMap<MyEntity, MyEntityDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.MyEntitySubDto1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.MyEntitySubDto1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src))
             
            .ForMember(dest => dest.MyEntitySubDto1.Myprop1, opt 
                                    => opt.MapFrom(src => src.MyProp1.SingleOrdefault(p => <My condition here>).MyProp1))
    
            .ReverseMap();
```

The mapping from `MyEntity` to `MyEntityDto` does work like a charm!
But the reverse mapping does not halas. I do not get any error, but the single `Myentity.MySubEntity` is not updated by AutoMapper.

Would you see any reason why?
Is there any way to have it work?

My first idea was to remove `.ReverseMap()` and write the whole reverse mapping.
But I do not even manage to write the first part correctly.
The first line generates an error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : 'Only member accesses are allowed. dest => dest Arg_ParamName_Name'

```cs
CreateMap<MyEntityDto, MyEntity>()
            .ForPath(dest => dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.MyEntitySubDto1));
```

I am not even sure that attempting to do the reverse mapping explicitly is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

For your scenario, to implement *reverse* mapping according to your logic, you should use [`IncludeMembers`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html#includemembers).

```cs
CreateMap<MyEntityDto, MyEntity>()
    .IncludeMembers(src => src.MyEntitySubDto1);
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mTzNyL)

Comment: Thx.
But I think your demo does not include the difficulty of this case.
MyEntity has a collection of MySubEntity. And I want to map only one of these MySubEntity to MyEntityDto.MySubEntityDto.
this is why there is a .SingleOrDefault(<myCondition>) in my code sample.

Comment: Please provide the complete implementation for MyEntity as mentioned. Especially the `MySubEntityDto`.